# Sliced assignment of Tensor to Variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to do a sliced assignment, but I'm getting the error below, even after I converted all of the tensors to Variables:

```
array = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((b,n,m)))
ones = tf.Variable(tf.ones((m)))
labels = tf.Variable(tf.ones((b), dtype=tf.int32))

for i in range(b):
    with tf.control_dependencies([array[i][labels[i]].assign(ones)]):
        array = tf.identity(array)

ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
```

How can I make this assignment in TensorFlow:

```
array[i][labels[i]] = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

?

Comment: Rather than create multiple variables, I'd create a NumPy array containing the initial values and then initialize the variable with the array.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino, in my code array is a tensor calculated earlier, and labels is a placeholder accepting Numpy array. But will your suggestion solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code below with the comments where necessary.

```
array = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((b,n,m)))
ones = tf.Variable(tf.ones((m)))
labels = tf.Variable(tf.ones((b), dtype=tf.int32)) 
#labels = np.ones(b,dtype=np.int8) if you want a array

with tf.control_dependencies([array[i,labels[i],:].assign(tf.ones(m)) for i in range(b)]): # should give the list of slice assignment here
 array = tf.identity(array) #conver to a tensor 

sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(array.eval()) #print the new array (optional, only to see the values)
```

Things you should note,

- `[array[i][labels[i]] --->  [array[i,labels[i],:]]` Seems like a syntax error for me.
- **tf.identity(array)** returns a **tensor** as the shape of **array**. When you assign that to the **array** again, then the **array** becomes a **tensor** and not  a
  **variable** anymore. You cannot do the **slice assignment** for a **tensor**.
- You need to provide a list of **slice assignments** as an argument to
  **tf.control_dependencies**

  Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not a typo. I want to do `array[i][labels[i]].assign(ones)`. I tried replacing tf.identity with a print statement, but I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: That's because of array[i][labels[i]].assign(ones)

Comment: So how can I do this assignment?

Comment: Ok, it works, but I don't want to print the array. How do I make sure the assignment gets executed? That  was the reason behind wrapping the assignment in the tf.control_dependencies statement.

Comment: Also, is there a way to do it all at once (not with a loop), when labels is an integer array?

Comment: I edited my answer, There was an error. Now works fine.

Comment: Could you pls go through my new answer. I'm really interested to know whether it's correct.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thanks! Any idea about how to get rid of the loop?

Comment: Why you need to get rid of the loop?

Comment: Speed. I want to parallelize it. Please take a look at this question if you want to take a crack at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422677